# Como pegar texto de uma Span com Class [VB.NET]

Tags: html, vb.net, classes, visual-basic-6, span

```
<span class="odometer-value">0</span>
```

Esse é o código.

Preciso pegar o resultado "0" e colocar em uma Label.

Porém as vezes pode ter ex: 10 (2 números) e o código vai ser:

```
<span class="odometer-value">1</span>
<span class="odometer-value">0</span>
```

Ou seja 2 span class separadas.

Tem como pegar todas as Span Class "odemeter-value" e jogar tudo pra uma Label?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Você vai ler esse código a partir de um WebBrowser?

Comment: O webbrowser precisa estar presente sim, mas está em enable=off

Comment: No caso um botão teria que usar o WebBrowser1.GetElementById pegar todas as span/class iguais e me dar o resultado em um textbox ou label.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, isso resolve seu problema

```js
function teste(){

    var textSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('odometer-value')
    var textLabel = document.getElementById('mylabel').textContent;

    for (let index = 0; index < textSpan.length; index++) {
        const element = textSpan[index];
        textLabel = textLabel + element.textContent;
    }
    document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = textLabel;
    
}
window.onload = teste();
```

```html
<span class="odometer-value">3</span>
    <span class="odometer-value">1</span>
    <span class="odometer-value">0</span>
    <br>
    <label id="mylabel">minha label: </label>
```